# How to invert colors in background image of a HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following `div`:

```
<div style="border-radius:50%; height:233px; width:423px; background-color:black; background-image:url(image2.gif);background-repeat:repeat; border:solid  1px; filter: invert(100%);-webkit-filter: invert(100%);"></div>
```

[image]

Now, I need to invert the colors of the background image to make it appear like:
[image]

I tried using

`filter: invert(100%);
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);`

but it inverts the whole `div` including the border making it look like:
[image]

How can I invert the colors of only the background image as opposed to that of the whole element?

**Note:** The above `div` is programmatically generated. The solution to invert the color of the border as well will need me to change the program to invert the color of the border, which may be in any format (hex, rgb, rgba, hsl, hsla, words etc), essentially bloating my code. However if no other option is available to me then I would do it but first I am hoping I can find a simpler solution.

Comment: maybe that's how filter works.. try `border: 1px solid white`.. to make it black after inverting.  [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDq58/1/).

Comment: @Mr_Green I am afraid I can't do that. All values are system generated and I can't change them.

Comment: Not a good idea.. use `!important` to override those styles. may be this is your only option here.

Comment: Could you post a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo that we can work with?

Comment: @DavidThomas sure, give me a minute.

Comment: @DavidThomas Mr_Green already had made such a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KDq58/1/

Comment: Would u mind sharing the code that generate that image?

Comment: How about using SVG image?

Answer (score 26):

You can set the background in a pseudo element, and keep the border in the div.

This way the filter will not affect the main element

```css
div {
    border-radius:50%;
    height:233px;
    width:423px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 170px;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQi3T.png);
    background-position: -21px -35px;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Text long</div>
```

Comment: Note that background set this way will cover the text content of the main div. It is necessary to wrap the content in another element and set its `z-index` higher.

Comment: @Qwerty not if you use `div:before` instead of `div:after`, I presume

Comment: @commonpike I have no memory of this place ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @commonpike I changed the snippet so that the text content shows.  It' only needs to set a negative z-index on the pseudo